# JQuery calculations producing NaN results

Tags: jquery, math

This code is fully functional in its job of revealing and hiding containers however the calculations are producing NaN. I have never tried Maths with JQuery before so prehaps one of you can show me where I have wrong.

```
function product_analysis_global() {
$(':checked').each(function(){
    $('#product_' + this.alt).css('display','block');
    $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val(this.value);
    var quantity = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
    var price = $('#product_price_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
    var duration = $('#product_duration_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
    var dives = $('#product_dives_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
    var hire = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val;

    $('#product_price_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(price * quantity);
    $('#product_duration_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(duration * quantity);
    $('#product_dives_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(dives * quantity);
    $('#product_hire_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(hire * quantity);
});
    $(':not(:checked)').each(function(){
        $('#product_' + this.alt).css('display','none');
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val('0');
        var quantity = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
        var price = $('#product_price_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
        var duration = $('#product_duration_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
        var dives = $('#product_dives_PRI_' + this.alt).val;
        var hire = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val;

    $('#product_price_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(price * quantity);
    $('#product_duration_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(duration * quantity);
    $('#product_dives_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(dives * quantity);
    $('#product_hire_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(hire * quantity);
```

});
}

Marvellous

Comment: Isn't .val suppost to be .val() ? Or am I rusty in my brain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your `.val`s (without brackets) need brackets after them: `()`. Otherwise you're getting the `val` **function** rather than the actual value the function returns.

E.g.

```
var quantity = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val(); // brackets
```

---

Also, **be careful** with `.val()`, which returns a **string**. In your scenario, there are no errors here, because you're only doing multiplication, and the strings will automatically get converted to numbers. But, if you have addition, strings will get **concatenated**: `'1' + '1' = '11'`. To prevent this (and be safe even in your example), put a single plus sign in front of the return value from `.val()` to convert the string into a number:

```
var quantity = +$('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val()` instead of `.val`

Answer (score 0):

You probably to calculations with strings. When in doubt if x is a number use:

```
parseInt(x)
```

to be sure is a number.